# Want to extract a value from String using patterns in java

Tags: java, regex, string, design-patterns

I have String and i want to extract the value of AGO_MATERIAL. ie 1400421-0010

> *ElementGroup name: 1-SSCFAP1301498_KB$4, description: AGO_MATERIAL, hidden: false,allowed: true, level: 0, uiType: uitypeIPC_nestedAssignmentBlock, accessKey: , tabIndex: , styleClasses: [Ljava.lang.String;@5d14ea56

ElementList: PropertyGroup

> ElementGroup name: $BASE_GROUP, description: General, hidden: false,
>   allowed: true, level: 0, uiType: uitypeIPC_propgroup, accessKey: ,
>   tabIndex: , styleClasses: [Ljava.lang.String;@824e3d8

ElementList:

> property: IS_IN_AGO, type: String, description: hej, helpValuesMethod:
>   null, value: 1-SSCFAP1301498_KB$2(SSCBFM901290), inputPattern: ,
>   height:
>
> property: AGO_MATERIAL, type: String, description: SSC Material, helpValuesMethod: null, value: 1400421-0010, inputPattern: , height: 4
>
> property: AGO_SEPARATOR, type: String, description: SSC Separator, helpValuesMethod: null, value: :, inputPattern: , height: 4

property: AGO_MTRL_QTY, type: String, description: Material Qty, helpValuesMethod: null, value: 2, inputPattern: , height: 4
>

```
          property: AGO_MATERIAL_NUMBER, type: String, description: AGO material number, helpValuesMethod: null, value: , inputPattern: , height: ";*
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Please properly format and provide code for review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex may complicate the code. If its a simple comparison you could use `indexOf` instead. Seeing the format of your strings it better to use properties then you have better control over the values. Eg

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Properties;

public class StringToProp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "property: IS_IN_AGO, type: String, description: hej, helpValuesMethod: null, value: 1-SSCFAP1301498_KB$2(SSCBFM901290), inputPattern: , height:";
        String str2 = "property: AGO_MATERIAL, type: String, description: SSC Material, helpValuesMethod: null, value: 1400421-0010, inputPattern: , height: 4";
        String str3 = "property: AGO_SEPARATOR, type: String, description: SSC Separator, helpValuesMethod: null, value: :, inputPattern: , height: 4";

        printProperty(str1);
        printProperty(str2);
        printProperty(str3);
    }

    private static void printProperty(String str) {
        String propertiesFormat = str.replaceAll(",", "\n");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new StringReader(propertiesFormat));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(properties.getProperty("property") + " : " + properties.getProperty("value"));
    }

}
```